# Android issue when starting activity

Tags: android, sqlite, quit

Hello I have a small problem with my app.

The starting activity connects to the sqlite database and retrieves an integer number that will check latter if it's 0, 1 or 2. Depending on the number, it will then open the respective activity.

```
final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); // Connection to the DB
final GokeyPin pinrow = db.getPin(1); // Grabs Pin + Pin Check + ID
int pin_check = pinrow.getYN(); //Grabs Pin Check | 0 = Never made a Pin | 1 = Has a pin | 2 = Doesn't want to have pin activated

    //Checks if you have created a pin

    if(pin_check==0) {

        // If 0 that means you haven't created a pin, so it brings you to the Createpin activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, Createpin.class);
        startActivity(intent);  

    }           

    // Checks if you have the pin active.

    if(pin_check==1) {
        // If 1 that means you want to use a pin and you have a pin. Goes to LogIn activity
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Start.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }   

    // Now it checks if you don't want to use a pin. That is 2. If so, it goes to Home activity

    if(pin_check==2) {
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(Start.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent3);             
    }
```

Then I update in the settings activity the number in the SQLite, and I exit with the back button from the device.

```
//In setting, checks if you have option to use or not a PIN
            RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupUsePin);
            int id2 = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (id2 == -1){
                //no item selected
            }

            //If user has option NO selected

            if (id2 == R.id.radioUPNo){
                // Grabs Pin + Pin Check + id from DB
                final GokeyPin pinrow2 = db.getPin(1); 
                //Updates Pin check -> 2 = mean not using
                pinrow2.setYN(2);
                db.updatePin(pinrow2);      
            }
                    // If Yes is selected
            if (id2 == R.id.radioUPYes){

                        // Grabs Pin + Pin Check + id From DB
                        final GokeyPin pinrow2 = db.getPin(1); 
                        //Updates Pin check - 1 = means using pin
                        pinrow2.setYN(1);
                        db.updatePin(pinrow2);
             }
```

Then the app saves the changes and I quit the app using the return button

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The problem is that when I start it again, it doesn't change for the activity wanted. For example if I have changed it to not use the pin then it should be going to the home activity, but instead, it still asks to login. If I don't login, but instead, if I use then the return button again, the next time I start the app, then it goes to the home without asking for a login.

The same happens if I have no login and I want to login.

If I go to the task manager after updating the settings and I force quit it, then it works fine.

Comment: where do you save data? where you resume?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you without seeing the code.

Comment: "The problem is that when I start it again, it doesn't change for the activity wanted, instead it keeps in the same, but If i exit again without changing the settings activity, then it changes." . elaborate

Comment: You'll need to look more into how Android re-uses Application objects, and the various flags you can use on an Intent or on the Activity entry of your Manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out the issue.

On the manifest after adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the starting activity, it fixed my problem.

Thanks to Chris I was able to focus more on the Manifest to find out the error.